# Bound the norm for Hessian by Laplacian Schauder estimate

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was trying to prove the following result which bound the Hessian by Laplacian for smooth function with compact supported.

For $u\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^n)$, we have

$$\|\partial_i\partial_j u\|_p \le C\|\Delta u\|_p$$ For $p>1$.

I can prove the case when $p = 2$ by directly integration by part.For the other case I guess we need to use the standard interpolation + duality arguement, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key observation is that $\partial_i\partial_j u$ = $R_iR_j u$, where $R_j$ is the multiplier operator
$$
\widehat{R_j f}(\xi) = \frac{\xi_j}{|\xi|} \widehat{f}(\xi).
$$
The fact that the operator $R_j$ is bounded in $L^p$ follows from the Calderón-Zygmund theorem (which uses interpolation + duality).

Comment: Thank you I found a note talking about this result, and it's called Schauder estimate. http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2015/REUPapers/Thoma.pdf